# How to check inferred numba type with nopython true?

Tags: python, numba

Without `nopython=True` `numba.typeof` reports variable type.

How do I check type of the variable with `nopython=True`?

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def f():
    a = 0
    print(numba.typeof(a))
f()
```

gives

```
UntypedAttributeError: Unknown attribute 'typeof' of type Module(<module 'numba'>)
```

I understand it can be done though `inspect_types()`, but for complicated functions it is not really convenient.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't - if you need to dispatch on type [`generated_jit`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/generated-jit.html#flexible-specializations-with-generated-jit) is probably the solution.

Comment: f.inspect_types() does what you wan't. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/troubleshoot.html f.inspect_llvm() is also interesting if you wan't to know what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @max9111 Thanks, but didn't I mention inspect_types() in PS? I wanted to check type of a single variable, which can be cumbersome with inspect_types for complicated functions

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read your question as carefully as I should ;) I couldn't get the output into a string object, otherwise it would be fairly easy to get the relevant data out of a string...

Answer (score -2):

comment out the decorator and rerun the code, then you should see the type from numba

Comment: The first sentence of my question says that even removing the 'nopython' argument to `jit()` is enough to get the type - no need to remove the decorator. I was asking how to check the type of the variable programmatically _with_ the decorator.